# Last RewriteRule catches everything

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

this is my .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js|php)$">
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    DefaultLanguage en-US
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Rewrite
    RewriteEngine On

    #catch everything that ends ".r" and route to resources.php
    #<-- WORKS IF THE CATCH ALL RULE IS COMMENTED OUT -->
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.r$ resources.php [L,QSA,NC]

    #catch everything listed in regex and throw 403 <-- WORKS FINE -->
    RewriteRule "\.(txt|json|xml|lock|log)" "-" [F]

    #TODO: BUG : Make this stop catching all
    #catch everything that the other 2 doesn't
    #<-- CATCHES EVERYTHING ALSO WHAT THE TOP RULE IS SUPPOSE TO -->
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
    #RewriteRule !"^(.*?)\.r$" index.php [QSA,NC,L]
    #RewriteRule ^(?!.*[.]r$).*$ index.php [QSA,NC]

</IfModule>
```

The Comments pretty much sums everything up.

I would like to be able to link to my resoruces with a link that ends with ".r". I have tested the regex and it seems to work correctly but i cant seem to figure out why it keeps showing the index when i enter a URL then ends with ".r".

I have been stuck with this problem for 4 hours now and i think i need some help i have looked around for answers on here(stackoverflow) but i cant seem to find a answer. I might have over looked the answer, i might have stared myself blind on a obvious mistake.

Also, i have checked the apache error logs and it's not throwing any errors so i have no idea where the mistake might be, but as i said i might have stared myself blind on the problem.

I rly hope you guys can help me :D

Thanks

Comment: Try adding **END** flag to your top rule so that it doesnt conflict with your other rules.

Comment: @starkeen if you post it as an answer i will mark it as the sloution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836886/last-rewriterule-catches-everything-also-what-the-top-rule-is-suppose-to#comment72783186_42836886) that fixed the issue, thanks to [starkeen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160747/starkeen)